# Referencing a range of columns from a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I know that i can reference all the columns in a pivot table including the grand total with pt.DataBodyRange.select from the excellent tutorial from https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/. However i want to reference All but the first 3 Columns. this does not seem to appear in the tutorial.

What i have so far: I am referencing each column separately then using the Union Function to combine them see below code where EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate are the column headings in the Pivot Table and Total is the totals column.
This seems to work fine, however i would like to know if its possible to do in one line without having to reference each column separately and then doing a Union of the ranges

```
Dim EmployeeID As Range
    Dim StartDate As Range
    Dim EndDate As Range
    Dim Total As Range
    Dim Rg As Range
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim TimeSheets() As Variant
    
    Set pt = shPivotTable.PivotTables("ptTimeSheets")
            
    With pt
        
        Set EmployeeID = .PivotFields("EmployeeID").DataRange
        Set StartDate = .PivotFields("StartDate").DataRange
        Set EndDate = .PivotFields("EndDate").DataRange
        Set Total = pt.RowRange.Offset(1, 6).Resize(pt.RowRange.Rows.count - 1)
        Debug.Print Total.Address
    End With
    Set Rg = Union(EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate, Total)
    Debug.Print Rg.Address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just resize the DataBodyRange to remove the first 3 columns:

```
pv.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, 3).Resize(, pv.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 3)
```

You can also create a range by using the start and end ranges:

```
Set rg = shPivotTable.Range(startRange,endRange)
```

Comment: Your first suggestion answers the immediate question , however if the number of columns vary , then that wont work, i like your second suggestion , could you please elaborate with examples please

Comment: I can't seem to get Set rg = shPivotTable.Range(startRange,endRange) to work

Comment: What do you mean by cannot get it to work?